# Why does rake_test_loader.rb fail (LoadError) when tests run in Rake under RVM ruby version 2.2.1

Tags: ruby, rake, rvm

I have just started to use RVM and have installed ruby version 2.2.1. I have a test project whose Rake test task I was successfully executing tests with the system version (2.0.0). When I then switch to 2.2.1 via RVM, the rake_test_loader fails with a LoadError.

As far I can see, there following are possible culprits

1. different version of Ruby in use
2. RVM environment is causing a problem
3. there is a problem with RVM and Rake

My code is packaged into standard gem structure. The rake file is as follows:

```
($LOAD_PATH << File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)).uniq!

require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rdoc/task'
require 'rubygems/package_task'

# Run All Tests Task
#
Rake::TestTask.new('test') do |t|
  t.pattern = 'test/**/*tests.rb'
  t.warning = true
end

task "default" => ["test"]
```

The exact error (with --trace flag set) is as follows:

> /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- test/unit (LoadError)     from
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'     from
>   /Users/Sancho/dev/git/joy/test/expression/core_staging_gallery_name_regexp_tests.rb:1:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'     from
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'     from
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '  from
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in
>   `each'    from
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in`
>   block in '     from
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in
>   `select'  from
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in`
>   ' rake aborted! Command failed with status (1): [ruby -w
>   -I"lib"  "/Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_test_loader.rb"
>   "test/**/*tests.rb" ]
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/testtask.rb:108:in
>   `block (3 levels) in define'
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/file_utils.rb:57:in`
>   call'
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/file_utils.rb:57:in
>   `sh'
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in`
>   sh'
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/file_utils.rb:96:in
>   `ruby'
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in`
>   ruby'
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/testtask.rb:104:in
>   `block (2 levels) in define'
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:58:in`
>   verbose'
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/testtask.rb:100:in
>   `block in define'
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in`
>   call'
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in
>   `block in execute'
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in`
>   each'
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in
>   `execute'
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in`
>   block in invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in
>   `mon_synchronize'
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in`
>   invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in
>   `invoke'
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in`
>   invoke_task'
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in
>   `block (2 levels) in top_level'
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in`
>   each'
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in
>   `block in top_level'
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in`
>   run_with_threads'
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in
>   `top_level'
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in`
>   block in run'
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in
>   `standard_exception_handling'
>   /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in`
>   run' /Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rake:33:in `'
>   Tasks: TOP => test

I am not sure if the above trace is that helpful, so I displayed the $LOAD_PATH when the tests are run under system ruby version 2.0.0 and RVM ruby version 2.2.1

$LOAD_PATH when tests fail under RVM ruby version 2.2.1:

```
"/Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0",
"/Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-darwin14",
"/Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby",
"/Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.2.0",
"/Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-darwin14",
"/Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby",
"/Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0",
"/Users/Sancho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-darwin14",
"/Users/Sancho/dev/git/joy/lib"
```

$LOAD_PATH when tests pass under 2.0.0:

```
"/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0",
"/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13",
"/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/universal-darwin13",
"/Library/Ruby/Site",
"/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0.0",
"/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13",
"/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13",
"/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby",
"/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0",
"/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13",
"/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13",
"/Users/Sancho/dev/git/joy/lib"
```

The root of the project is /Users/Sancho/dev/git/joy/

Tests are located at /Users/Sancho/dev/git/joy/test/.../*_tests.rb

Code under test located at /Users/Sancho/dev/git/joy/lib/joy/.../*.rb

So to summarise, the same code (invoked by rake test task) is being executed in both scenarios, 1 passes the other fails. The first scenario is using the system version of ruby (version 2.0.0, passes) and the second scenario is RVM ruby version 2.2.1 (fails).

So, what's causing the LoadError problem?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I have installed version 2.0.0p598 via RVM (as opposed to the system version 2.0.0p481. (I had to use p598 because p481 is no longer available).
Using version 2.0.0p598, the tests worked fine. This rules out RVM in itself being a problem and leads me to believe there is an issue with the latest version of ruby 2.2.1. Can anyone shed any light on this?

UPDATE No 2:
Ruby version 2.1.1p76 also works.

Comment: Bug reported to Ruby at ruby-lang.org (issue #11041)

Comment: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11041 it was closed 4 years ago in 2019